# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, web-testing, webautomation

I am facing some issue in my test script. What am I doing wrong here? Before that just an overview beforehand, its website testing in python and selenium using pytest. My selenium is v4.18.1 and Chrome v122.0.6261.112

conftest.py

[image]

Test_Regis.py:

[image]

I got this attribute error. But same I have written in very basic way. I have also written very basic of the same automation script. Below is same code as above.

[image]

This works fine. I do not understand what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: BTW: Don't upload images of code. Extract a [mcve] and then post it as text, so people can copy'n'paste it into a file to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `driver` created in `setup`. I would also rename `setup` to `driver`:

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    chrome_driver.maximize_window()
    chrome_driver.get("...")
    return chrome_driver
```

```py
# test_it.py
class TestRegistration:
    def test_reg001(self, driver):
        # Do something with driver
        pass
```

The key here is to return the driver you created.